# Admin UI for PRC and REP roles not working on Azure PaaS on vanilla Sitecore 9

Tags: admin-pages, processing

I have problem accessing admin UI on Processing and Reporting role on Sitecore 9. We use XP fully scaled environment deployed on Azure via 'Sitecore® Experience Cloud' from Azure Market place.

After loging via admin login screen I get following error on /sitecore/shell/
(note: /sitecore/admin/ works):

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Postcondition 'value should not be null' failed.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.PostconditionException: Postcondition 'value should not be null' failed.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[PostconditionException: Postcondition 'value should not be null' failed.]
   Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.EnsuresValidator`1.ThrowExceptionCore(String condition, String additionalMessage, ConstraintViolationType type) +156
   Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.Throw.ValueShouldNotBeNull(ConditionValidator`1 validator, String conditionDescription) +144
   Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.ValidatorExtensions.IsNotNull(ConditionValidator`1 validator) +62

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +295
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters) +119
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandManager.ReadCommands() +664
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandManager..cctor() +68

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandManager' threw an exception.]
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandManager.GetCommand(String name) +0
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Menu.AddMenuItem(Control parent, Item child, String target, CommandContext context) +618
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Menu.AddFromDataSource(Item item, Control parent, String target, CommandContext context) +379
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Menu.AddFromDataSource(Item item, String target) +82
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.DataContextMenu.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +67
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1381
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Actually, the only reason was, that we don't want to run DEF from CM role. Rather we would like to utilize the Processing role for this task.

Answer (score 1):

By some experiments (comparing assemblies on PRC and CM roles, disabling different commands, ...) I have realized that the issue is caused by **marketingtaxonomy:deploy** command from the *Sitecore.Marketing.Client.config* file. Simply, if I disable it, the UI is working properly.

Unfortunately, the root cause is not understandable still. Hopefully, I'll have some more time to resolve that and come back here with the happy-end...

Answer (score 0):

The Sitecore UI should not be used on PRC and REP roles. Those servers are NOT for Authoring. Marketing Definitions are by design broken, because on REP roles it is read only, on CM roles they are remote xDB, and on Processing, they are read only.

While I can't prove this, I suspect that it is intentionally broken.

Only use the Sitecore UI on the Content Management only role in a XP1 topology.

This behavior is the same on On Prem and Azure PaaS.

Comment: What is your recomendation when one needs to install a hotfix into the processing server and it's a sitecore package?

Comment: Install the package first on the CM server. Then unzip the package and push the files to the Processing and Reporting servers only. I would recommend baking this into your deployment processes. We have a process where we can add Sitecore packages for deployment, and scripted out the deployment on all of the servers (including automatic package install on the CM server)